# Update a javascript object using non undefined properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got a function to update an object:

```
_.each(user, function(value, key, obj) {
  if (user[key] !== undefined) {
    self.user[key] = user[key];
  }
});
```

It lets me update users like this:

```
let user = new User();
user.verified = true;
self.sessionService.updateSession(user);
```

I only need to specify properties that are going to be updated by checking for undefined, can this be simplified or written more efficient?

Comment: Well you may use *value* if its already there...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using underscore:

```
_.assign(self.user, _.omit(user, _.isUndefined))
```

This works by creating an object where all the keys with undefined values are omitted using [**omit**](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) and the [**isUndefined**](http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined) predicate.

This object is then used with [**assign**](http://underscorejs.org/#assign) to update the `self.user` object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you need, but you can set a variable to new value if it's undefined/null/"" like this:

```
myVar = myVar || newValue;
```

If myVar is defined, the old value will be kept. If not, it will be assigned to newValue.

Comment: No, that is not true. myVar = 0 and newValue = 27 would also be updated. expression == false is not the same as expression === undefined